# Workflow Foundation Receive Activity

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I am working on simple Workflow Foundation that uses a simple ASP.NET page as its client.

I am using the page to collect a loan amount and month amount to calculate per month loan amount.

I have two WCF services that I am going to be using to do this.

In the WF application, I begin with a "Receive Activity" which waits for a request from the response. In order to do this, I must define the "ServiceContractName" in the properties. What is this SPECIFICALLY referring to?

**EDIT**
Looking at the wsdl for one of the services I am using is found at the following URL:

http://vlab.asu.edu:9135/ServiceRepository/MonthlyPayment/Service.svc?wsdl

and it has the following in it which I think might help me to get the proper namespace to use for the **ServiceContractName**:

soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/CalculateMonthlyPayments"

I am still insure what to use for the proper namespace of the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceContractName is the namespace and the name of the service - e.g., http://www.tempuri.org/MyService.

See [Combining WCF and WF4](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/08/05/combining-wcf-and-wf4.aspx) - it seems to go into some detail on combining Workflow Foundation and WCF.

(I've personally never used Workflow Foundation, but have done quite a bit with WCF).

Comment: I am looking at the WSDL for one of the services I am using. It is located at the following address:http://vlab.asu.edu:9135/ServiceRepository/MonthlyPayment/Service.svc?wsdl  but I noticed in the wsdl the following which might hint what the namespace would be soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService/CalculateMonthlyPayments"   so what would I use for the ServiceContractName?

Comment: The ServiceContractName would be http://tempuri.org/IService.  (Don't forget the http:// - it keeps disappearing when i post the comment).  CalculateMonthlyPayments is an operation (method) exposed by the service.